# Index was outside bounds of array error whilst working with a ListBox

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listbox, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm attempting to import data from one `ListBox` to another whilst eliminating commas, quotations and other unnecessary parts of the text.

For some reason, when I try to run it and attempt to transfer the data over I get the error:

> Index was outside bounds of array.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub LoadButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoadButton.Click

    'check contents of list box
    If RawDataListBox.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No rows in list box")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' split the data and store it in a structure
    Try

        Dim counterInteger As Integer = 1
        Dim AbsDataStructure(RawDataListBox.Items.Count) As absdata
        Dim FinalDataOutputString As String

        While counterInteger < RawDataListBox.Items.Count
            'read one line/row into a string
            Dim AbsSingleLineString As String = RawDataListBox.Items(counterInteger).ToString
            'Split string by comma
            Dim AbsDataString As String() = AbsSingleLineString.Split(","c) 'need to also get rid of the quotation marks on data

            With AbsDataStructure(counterInteger)
                .LocationNameString = AbsDataString(0)
                .TypeString = AbsDataString(1)
                .StateString = AbsDataString(2)
                .MeasureString = AbsDataString(3)
                .LocalGovernmentAreaString = AbsDataString(4)
                .TotalMalesInteger = Integer.Parse(AbsDataString(5))
                .TotalFemalesInteger = Integer.Parse(AbsDataString(6))
                .FrequencyString = AbsDataString(7)
                .PercentMalesDouble = Double.Parse(AbsDataString(8))
                .PercentFemalesDouble = Double.Parse(AbsDataString(9))
                .TotalMalesAndFemalesInteger = .TotalMalesInteger + .TotalFemalesInteger
            End With

            'BELOW BLOCK OF CODE DOESNT WORK FOR SOME REASON
            FinalDataOutputString = "Cities and Regions: " + AbsDataStructure(counterInteger).LocationNameString + ","
            FinalDataOutputString += "Type: " + AbsDataStructure(counterInteger).TypeString + ","
            FinalDataOutputString += "State: " + AbsDataStructure(counterInteger).StateString + ","
            FinalDataOutputString += "Females: " + AbsDataStructure(counterInteger).TotalFemalesInteger.ToString + ","
            FinalDataOutputString += "Males: " + AbsDataStructure(counterInteger).TotalMalesInteger.ToString + ","
            FinalDataOutputString += "%Female: " + AbsDataStructure(counterInteger).PercentFemalesDouble.ToString + ","
            FinalDataOutputString += "%Male: " + AbsDataStructure(counterInteger).PercentMalesDouble.ToString + ","
            FinalDataOutputString += "Total Males and Females: " + AbsDataStructure(counterInteger).TotalMalesAndFemalesInteger.ToString
            'add to line in listbox
            FinalDataListBox.Items.Add(FinalDataOutputString)

            counterInteger += 1
            'when counterinteger is 10 i get inputstring was not in correct format
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you not using `For Each`?

Comment: For what section? Sorry I am new to pseudolanguage - only a month into my course.

Comment: Is "absdata" a Class or Structure?

Comment: "absdata" is a structure.

Comment: Why are you using an array of them?  It doesn't get used anywhere else because it is local.  You could just declare a single new instance inside the while loop and use that.

Comment: Set  `counterInteger` to 0 when you start and change this `While counterInteger < RawDataListBox.Items.Count` to `While counterInteger < RawDataListBox.Items.Count - 1` at a guess. A `For i = 0 to RawDataListBox.Items.Count - 1` would make more sense and instead of `counterInteger` use `i`

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic is a zero-based index language.  It's hard to say if this is the issue, but I think it might be the fact that `counterInteger` is set to `1`.  When you initiate `AbsDataStructure` you set its size to `RawDataListBox.Items.Count`.  Try setting `counterInteger` to `0`.

Comment: Thank you for your correspondence,  I tried that but still, the error prevails.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using that array of structure outside of the method so I'd simplify that down to:

```
Private Sub LoadButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoadButton.Click
    If RawDataListBox.Items.Count > 0 Then
        Dim FinalDataValues As New List(Of String)

        For Each rawData As String In RawDataListBox.Items
            Try
                Dim AbsDataString As String() = rawData.Split(","c)

                Dim TotalFemalesInteger As Integer = Integer.Parse(AbsDataString(6))
                Dim TotalMalesInteger As Integer = Integer.Parse(AbsDataString(5))
                Dim PercentMalesDouble As Double = Double.Parse(AbsDataString(8))
                Dim PercentFemalesDouble As Double = Double.Parse(AbsDataString(9))

                FinalDataValues.Clear()
                FinalDataValues.Add("Cities and Regions: " + AbsDataString(0))
                FinalDataValues.Add("Type: " + AbsDataString(1))
                FinalDataValues.Add("State: " + AbsDataString(2))
                FinalDataValues.Add("Females: " + TotalFemalesInteger.ToString)
                FinalDataValues.Add("Males: " + TotalMalesInteger.ToString)
                FinalDataValues.Add("%Female: " + PercentFemalesDouble.ToString)
                FinalDataValues.Add("%Male: " + PercentMalesDouble.ToString)
                FinalDataValues.Add("Total Males and Females: " + (TotalFemalesInteger + TotalMalesInteger).ToString)

                FinalDataListBox.Items.Add(String.Join(",", FinalDataValues.ToArray))
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Line: " & rawData & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.ToString, "Error Parsing Line")
            End Try
        Next
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No rows in list box")
    End If
End Sub
```